# Set DisplayMemberPath of ListBox that is bound to an ObservableCollection of ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

How do I set the `DisplayMemberPath` of `ListBox` that is bound to an `ObservableCollection` of `ObservableCollection`'s?  Everything is working correctly.  The `ListBox` correctly shows the `ObservableCollection` in it.  When the user selects one in the `ListBox` the data of the `ObservableCollection` is displayed to `DataGrid`.  The only issue is that ListBox displays `(collection)` for each `ObservableCollection` (not something descriptive).  Figuring I would need to put a converter in I did this;

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyCollection}" 
DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CollectionConverter}}" />
```

Then have a standard converter like this;

```
public class CollectionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //Convert Logic
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //ConvertBack logic
    }
}
```

Problem is that the `Convert` and `ConvertBack` never fire.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not distill this into a stand alone example which you can present here, with the actual data and bindings which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Why are you binding to an ObservableCollection of collections? What is the ListBox supposed to display?

Comment: There is nothing "descriptive" about an ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor the first collection like this:

```
class NamedObservableCollection : ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<MyItem>> 
{  
    public string Name { get; private set;}

    public NamedObservableCollection(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyCollection}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"}/>
```